# Intersection - shapefile with 1000's of overlapping polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, intersection, overlapping-features

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have two shapefiles, one being a single USA county outline (1 polygon) and another with 1000s of polygons representing wildfire shapes for an entire USA state. When I run an Intersect, it seems to create the correct looking shapefile but when I dig into the attribute table, there is lots of weird data. I want to retain the information of the wildfires within the county area and for fires that are only partly in the county, I want to know about them and the area that overlaps.

Comment: What do you mean by weird data number of monkeys in trees??? Suggest you explain what is weird about it?

Comment: I dont know what it has really done but now i have many shapes underlying that are the same shape and size in the same location. I think that means the intersection is happening between all polygons (because so many overlap) which causes lots of double counting

Comment: Correct, that is how Intersect works.  It creates polygons for all intersections, including intersections within the same shapefile.

Comment: Would a simple Select by Location to get the subset of wildfires in your county work?

Comment: @lambertji what do you mean? how would i do that? as far as i know the fire shapes dont know where they are that is why i have the county shape file

Comment: If you have ArcGIS Advanced you might try an Identity overlay of the fires with the counties.  You might also look at a spatial join of the counties to the fires?

Comment: i just tried an indentity run and it doesnt seem to work. I have arcgis pro